# Blank SSHFS mount folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, file-manager, sshfs

I am attempting to mount a remote directory located on my web server to a directory in my xUbuntu installation hosted in a VirtualBox.

I'm using the following command syntax:

```
sshfs root@*.*.*.*:/var/www Desktop/RemoteMount
```

Using the file manager, I navigate to the **Desktop/RemoteMount** directory but find it entirely blank. The SSHFS command above executed with no indication of an error.

Completely by chance, I use the terminal to long list the contents of the **Desktop/RemoteMount** directory and it shows all the data I was expecting to see in the file manager.

Why does the file manager not show my remotely mounted data, and how I might fix it?

Comment: If root is not the owner of `/var/www` on remote then don't mount by root, mount as simple user. Please provide feedback. As I cannot replicated the issue at my end.

Comment: @Jord: I started by attempting to mount as a non-super-user but encountered the same issue. I attempted the SU approach to circumvent the problem

Comment: Have you tried with a different mount point than "Desktop/RemoteMount"? It's possible your desktop environment is interfering, since "~/Desktop" is often its playground...

Comment: I have the same problem. Mounted a remote directory via sshfs, the tried to ls the contents of that directory in an SSH session on the remote system: it is empty. Strange.

Comment: I fixed the same issue by unmounting the folder and deleting it. Afterward, it worked fine.

Comment: @Jakov Had the same problem as OP (empty dir), tried your tip and it worked. Is this some old bug (Q is from 2014) that came back? I sadly have no time to do extensive diagnostics now but that *is* some odd behaviour, indeed.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing local mountpoint.

sshfs -o idmap=user mika@192.168.1.2:/home/mika/remotepoint /home/mika/localmountpoint.

And You need to have localmount folder exist.

thanks Mika

Comment: his local mount point is there, `Desktop/RemoteMount`